# Where returned values don't end with a &?

Tags: powershell

Is there a way to add a `where` clause where the returned values don't end with a `&`?

```
$Test = Get-Content $List | Where ??? Does not end with a &
```

Comment: Try: `Where-Object {$_ -notmatch "&$"}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several ways of checking this (ordered by performance, best to worst):

- `... | Where-Object { -not $_.EndsWith('&') }`
- `... | Where-Object { $_ -notlike '*&' }`
- `... | Where-Object { $_ -notmatch '&$' }`

Answer (score 2):

You can use -notmatch and then the regular expression &$

```
$Test = Get-Content $List | ?{$_ -notmatch "&$" }
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a "positive" interpretation:

```
echo 'hi&' | select-string '[^&]$'
echo hi    | select-string '[^&]$'

hi
```

Note that `Select-String` returns a matchinfo object.  `Where-Object` may be less annoying.  Or even [`findstr`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/cc732459%28v%3dws.11%29).

Comment: FTR, that's just moving the negation into the regular expression (`[^...]`).

Comment: `findstr` might actually not be a bad choice (`... | findstr /v "&$"`).